# How to setup pgBadger to work with journal correctly

Tags: postgresql, pgbadger, systemd, journald

I'm wondering how make pgBadger correctly work with systemd journal.

The documentatin says, that `--journalctl` takes over the command for journalctl that is used to filter. According to documentation it says:

```
 pgbadger --journalctl 'journalctl -u postgresql-9.5'
```

(Quote from man page -- so sic!)

This activated with the common settings that pgbadger recommds I still cannot extract data.

So what are the correct steps on doing it? How e.g. needs ne logstring be formated?

(Of course I tried several different settings and different calls/versions of "--journalctl … etc. As this is no forum asking it a s a general "howto" question seems to be more legit to me)

Comment: How exactly did you invoke the command? What was the output? What did you expect instead?

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but you should upgrade to a supported version of PostgreSQL (9.4 is 5.5 years out of support) - see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) - 15 is at version 6 so should be stable if you/your organisation have/has a conservative updating policy.

Comment: This is a quote from the man-page of pgbadger. I'm using pg15+